# Converter corretamente valor em notação científica para texto em R

Tags: r

Estou um pouco sem rumo com um problema com o meu data frame. Baixo uma tabela de um SQL server e uma das colunas traz os números de cada processo. Esse valor é uma sequência numérica longa que o R converte para notação científica. O problema é que quando altero a coluna para texto ele traz o número errado. Como faço para o R entender o número correto?

Segue um código para ilustrar o problema:
Quando mudo para texto o resultado vem com o final 6 e não 7.

```
df <- data.frame(Processo = (25351001641201357))
df

> df
    Processo
   1 2.5351e+16

df1 <- as.character(df$Processo)
df1

> df1
[1] "25351001641201356"
```

Acrescentando o resultado da solução sugerida, mas que ainda não funcionou.

```
> options(scipen = 1e9)
> df <- data.frame(Processo = c(25351001641201357))
> df
           Processo
1 25351001641201356

> as.character(format(df, scientific = FALSE))
[1] "25351001641201356"
```

Estou usando o Windows 10 Home Single Language 64bits
RStudio Version 1.4.1106

Comment: Não pode ler como `character`?

Comment: É que a tabela é fornecida por um outro setor do meu trabalho. Não tenho como alterar a forma que os dados chegam.

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar `format` para especificar o formato de exibição:

```
n <- c(25351001641201357706367, 72952982679250725702754)

as.character(n)
#> [1] "2.53510016412014e+22" "7.29529826792507e+22"

as.character(format(n, scientific = FALSE))
#> [1] "25351001641201359126528" "72952982679250725240832"
```

Ou usar `options` para mudar o limite para notação científica para um valor bastante alto, fazendo com que não seja usada durante toda sessão de trabalho:

```
options(scipen = 1e6)

as.character(n)
#> [1] "25351001641201359126528" "72952982679250725240832"
```

## Atualizado: número grande de dígitos

Da ajuda para `integer` (tradução livre minha):

> Observe que as implementações atuais de R usam inteiros de 32 bits para vetores de inteiros. Portanto, o intervalo de inteiros representáveis é restrito a cerca de +/-2*10^9.

Pode checar o limite exato com `.Machine$integer.max`. Valores maiores são convertidos automaticamente para *double*:

```
n <- 25351001641201357

print(n, digits = 22)
#> [1] 25351001641201356

class(n)
#> [1] "numeric"

is.integer(n)
#> [1] FALSE

is.double(n)
#> [1] TRUE
```

O porque disso exige uma explicação muito longa para uma resposta do SO, mas o cálculo do número de dígitos significativos no R depende da biblioteca C implementada e segue padrão internacional (pode [ler mais na Wikipedia em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)).

A solução para isso é carregar os dados como `character`. Como o R converte automaticamente valores altos para double, mesmo pacotes que implementam limites maiores (p.e. gmp) requerem que sejam lidos primeiro como string.

Comment: Carlos, obrigado pelo resposta. Infelizmente o problema ainda não foi resolvido. 
testei os códigos:    `options(scipen = 1e9)                                                                       
             df <- data.frame(Processo = c(25351001641201357,25351001641201385,25351123456202188))                 
                      df                                                                                      
           Processo
1 25351001641201356
2 25351001641201384
3 25351123456202188`

Comment: @rodgreg, não poste bloco de código nos comentários; se necessário edite a pergunte. Funciona usando `format(..., scientific = FALSE)`? Se não, edite a pergunte para incluir esse detalhe e informe também os dados do seu sistema/sessão.

Comment: @rodgreg, desculpe a demora em responder. Seu problema está relacionado com número de dígitos significativos e é um pouco mais complicado do que só mudar a exibição. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Answer (score -4):

```
options(scipen = 999)

df <- data.frame(Processo = (25351001641201357))
df
```

Comment: Quando for responder perguntas, tente não apenas jogar códigos, mas também explicar o que foi feito e o porquê.